# Device interfacing using SMBus on Beaglebone Black

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, i2c, serial-communication, device-tree

I am using ADM1032ARMZ-2R temperature sensor (as a beginner I am not allowed to post more than 2 links here, I have already posted 2 links for the images below - For datasheet please google ADM1032ARMZ-2R) with Beaglebone Black Rev C having pre-installed Debian (kernel - 3.8.13) . The datasheet of ADM1032 says that chip is available for communication at address 0x4D via SMBus Protocol. I have never worked on SMbus before but found that I2C is compatible with SMBus for 100 KHz and less. I tried doing following things

1. I wrote a device tree overlay. It looks like following (I have kept the frequency as 100 KHz)

   // Device Tree Overlay for I2C1 uses Pins P9.17(SCLK) & P9.18(SDA)

   ```
   /dts-v1/;
   /plugin/; 
   / {
           compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";
           part-number = "BBB-I2C1-4D";
           version = "00A0";
           exclusive-use =
                   "P9.18",        /* i2c1_sda */
                   "P9.17",        /* i2c1_scl */
                   /* the hardware ip uses */

           fragment@0 {
                   target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
                   __overlay__ {
                           bb_i2c1_pins: pinmux_bb_i2c1_pins {
                                   pinctrl-single,pins = <
                                           0x158 0x72      /* spi0_d1.i2c1_sda, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | INPUT_PULLUP | MODE2 */
                                           0x15c 0x72      /* spi0_cs0.i2c1_scl, SLEWCTRL_SLOW | INPUT_PULLUP | MODE2 */
                                   >;
                           };
                   };
           };

           fragment@1 {
                   target = <&i2c1>;
                   __overlay__ {
                           status = "okay";
                           pinctrl-names = "default";
                           pinctrl-0 = <&bb_i2c1_pins>;

                           clock-frequency = <100000>;
                           #address-cells = <1>;
                           #size-cells = <0>;

                           /* adding adm1032 as i2c child device on the bus here */

                           tempsense: tempsense@4d {
                                   compatible = "onsemi,adm1032";
                                   reg = <0x4d>;                    
                           };
                   };
           };
   };
   ```
2. Compiled this file, copied the resultant .dtbo file in the /lib/firmware directory and successfully inserted it as a virtual cape in the /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.9/slots using echo command. [It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVTQe.jpg)
3. I tried to observe the correctness of the above work using the following command

> dtc -f -I fs /proc/device-tree | less

[Intended things are happening and it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zNBf.jpg) (Please note that, for i2c1, the "ti,hwmods" field in the image shows "i2c2", but its actually i2c1 so please don't worry about it. I have read about it made sure that whatever it's showing is correct)

4. Now I am trying to do

> i2cdetect -r 1

But I am not able to detect anything

at 0x02, there is a Status register available for reading

> i2cget -y -f 0x4d 0x02

I get ***Read failed*** response

Where am I going wrong ? Please help.